# Present a List at the current date

Tags: swiftui

In my app I've a List view with an array of Dates, `var calcWeights : [EggDay]`

```
struct EggDay: Identifiable {

    var id : Int
    var date : Date 
    var weight : Double
    var measured : Bool
    var dailyLoss : Double

    init (id : Int, date: Date, weight : Double, measured : Bool, dailyLoss : Double) {
        self.id = id
        self.date = date
        self.weight = weight
        self.measured = measured
        self.dailyLoss = dailyLoss
    }
}
```

It is sorted on the date, starting from day 1, as you can see in View 1. What I would like to achieve is View 2... so the List should be presented on the current day.

[image: standard List based on days]
[image: List based on current date]

Comment: Do you want the list to be scrolled to today or only show eggs from today onwards?

Comment: The user must be able to scroll back up to day 1. So I want the list to be scrolled to today. Just convenience for the user... so the user can immediately select the current day.